# How can I exclude something if a specific string is provided in the output?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

So I wrote this code with the help of Stack Overflow users that transfers points to an individual based on whether "++" or "--" appears behind an individual.

```
def get_name(input):
    return input.replace("+", "").replace("-", "")
def keep(actions: list):
    g = {}
    for s in actions:
        if '->' in s:
            names = s.split('->')
            g[names[1]] = g[names[0]]
            g[names[0]] = 0
        else:
            name = get_name(s)
            if name not in g:
                g[name] = 0
            if "++" in s:
                g[name] += 1
            if "--" in s:
                g[name] -= 1
    return {x:g[x] for x in g if g[x] != 0}
print(keep(["Jim++", "John--", "Jeff++", "Jim++", "John--", "John->Jeff",
"Jeff--", "June++", "Home->House"]))
```

So most of the program is alright, however, when I put `"Home->House"` into it, it returns a **KeyError**. I kinda understand why it does that, but I'm clueless as to how to fix that...

I tried browsing the internet for solutions but all they recommended was to use .get(), which doesn't really help me solve the issue.

How can I make my output just neglect if like an element doesn't have "++" or "--" in it... like how can I make sure if an input is just "Jim" instead of "Jim++" or "Jim--", the function would just neglect it...

So in my example, if the input for `keep` is

```
["Jim++", "John--", "Jeff++", "Jim++", "John--", "John->Jeff", "Jeff--", "June++", "Home->House "]
```

the output would be

```
{'Jeff': -2, 'June': 1, 'Jim': 2}
```

instead of KeyError

Comment: do you know how to use `get` instead of `[]` when accessing a dictionary

Comment: `"Home>House "` - is that a typo? Because the full example has `->`.

Comment: @MSalters yep it is. Sorry for that, gonna edit that real quick

Comment: g[names[1]] = g.get(names[0], 0)

Answer (score 1):

You get `KeyError` because `g[names[1]] = g[names[0]]` is trying to access element in dictionary that isn't there. You get the same issue with simple `print(keep(["John->Jeff"]))`, because there are no `++` or `--` actions executed first to initialise those keys ("John" and "Jeff" in `g`

Based on your desired output you want to ignore such actions that are for non existing keys.
Add `if names[1] in g and names[0] in g:` into your `keep` implementation i.e.
Edit: also `g[names[1]] = g[names[0]]` needs to change to `g[names[1]] += g[names[0]]` to product correct outcome.

```
def get_name(input):
    return input.replace("+", "").replace("-", "")

def keep(actions: list):
    g = {}
    for s in actions:
        if "->" in s:
            names = s.split("->")
            if names[1] in g and names[0] in g:
                g[names[1]] += g[names[0]]
                g[names[0]] = 0
        else:
            name = get_name(s)
            if name not in g:
                g[name] = 0
            if "++" in s:
                g[name] += 1
            if "--" in s:
                g[name] -= 1
    return {x: g[x] for x in g if g[x] != 0}
```

Comment: Please note that the OP output is like this {'Jeff':** -2**, 'June': 1, 'Jim': 2} instead of {'Jim': 2, 'Jeff': **-3**, 'June': 1}

Comment: @gold_cy, It's about the value of 'Jeff': -3.

Comment: I see, that's a second thing then, `g[names[1]] = g[names[0]]` needs to change to `g[names[1]] += g[names[0]]` to "transfer" value and take previous value into account.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when you get `Home->House`, it's the first appearence of both the keys. That's why you get `KeyError` when you try to execute `g[names[1] = g[names[0]]`: `g[names[0]]` is `g['Home']`, but this entry doesn't exist in your dict. You can simply solve swapping the order of the lines:

```py
if '->' in s:
   names = s.split('->')
   g[names[0]] = 0
   g[names[1]] = g[names[0]]
```

To neglect strings which haven't the "++" or the "--", you can simply add an if before performing `get_name(s)`:

```py
else:
   if '++' in s or '--' in s:
      name = get_name(s)
      if name not in g:
         g[name] = 0
      if "++" in s:
         g[name] += 1
      if "--" in s:
         g[name] -= 1
```

This code returns the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually does ignore examples which do not include "++" or "--" in the else-section of your function.

The `KeyError` occurs because neither "Home" nor "House" appear in the List of input strings before you try to move the entry of "Home" into the entry of "House". Because the keys "Home" and "House" are not in your dictionary `g` you get a `KeyError`.

Below is a solution which does what you want.

```
def get_name(input):
    return input.replace("+", "").replace("-", "")

def keep(actions: list):
    g = {}
    for s in actions:
        if '->' in s:
            names = s.split('->')
            if names[0] in g.keys() and names[1] in g.keys():
                g[names[1]] = g[names[0]] + g[names[1]]
                g[names[0]] = 0
        else:
            name = get_name(s)
            if name not in g:
                g[name] = 0
            if "++" in s:
                g[name] += 1
            if "--" in s:
                g[name] -= 1
    return {x:g[x] for x in g if g[x] != 0}
print(keep(["Jim++", "John--", "Jeff++", "Jim++", "John", "John--", "John->Jeff",
"Jeff--", "June++", "Home->House"]))
```

I added a check to make sure the keys exist in dict `d` when the input string includes a "->".

In order to get the output you indicated in your question, which includes `'Jeff': -2`, you also need to make sure to **add** the value of the original key to the value of the new key. This is done in line

```
g[names[1]] = g[names[0]] + g[names[1]]
```

Otherwise the output will say `'Jeff': -3` as the input string `"Jeff++"` will be ignored.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for ur explaination, but when I tried to put this as input print(keep(["Jim++", "John--", "Jeff++", "Jim++", "John", "John--", "John->Jeff",
"Jeff--", "June++", "Home->House"])), the output returns an Error... what should I do to fix that??

Comment: I copy and pasted your input string and I get no error but the correct output. Are you using python2 or python3?

Comment: I'm using python 3.6 rn

Comment: Oops I meant print(keep([["Jim++", "John--", "Jeff++", "Jim++", "John--", "John->Jeff", "Jeff--", "June++"]]))... yea this code creates an error, not the previous one

Comment: That's because you use a List of Lists as an input. If you remove the extra `[` and `]` it should work fine.